# Error en solicitud .get con request en python

Tags: python, requests

soy nuevo en esto de la programacion con python. Estoy intentando una solicitud .get a una `ip address` en red esperando que me devuelva la estructura `html` para hacer uso de algunos datos.

**este es mi codigo**

```
import requests

proxies = {
   'http': 'http://99.90.124.9/',
   'https': 'https://99.90.124.9/',
}
response : url= 'http://99.90.124.9/'

print(res.text)
```

**y esto es lo que me arroja**

```
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-ee7de02c0594> in <module>()
      7 response : url= 'http://99.90.124.9/'
      8 
----> 9 print(res.text)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Yo no veo la variable `res`

Comment: Estas mostrando un error que viene de un código que no conocemos (como dice el compañero, hace falta la variable res). Y es justo la linea del error la que falta. Cualquier ayuda que se te intente dar bajo esas condiciones serian como jugar a las adivinansas.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estas teniendo en la porción de código de compartiste es que en ningún momento estas haciendo la petición a la url.
Si bien tenes un typo en el naming de las variables, en terminos practicos lo que estas queriendo hacer es equivalente a:

```
'mi cadena de texto'.text
```

Te sugiero que le pegues un vistazo a la documentacion oficial de la libreria: https://pypi.org/project/requests/

En el primer ejemplo vas a poder encontrar como hacer uso de `requests.get`
Saludos!

Comment: No olvides colocar también el ejemplo en tu respuesta. Si el contenido del enlace que proporcionas llega a modificarse, ¿cómo futuros lectores más adelante sabrán cuál era el _primer ejemplo_? Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

gracias por sus respuesta estuve modificando un poco el código tomando en cuenta los puntos de vista de cada quien, y al igual hice uso de las herramientas que me sugirieron. Aunque sigo teniendo un problema.

Tratare de expresarle con un ejemplo

Cuando hago una solicitud con requests.get

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://github.com/')

r.text
```

lo que me va a devolver es esto:

[image: Ejemplo del código ejecutado]

para mi caso la url "http" no es una pagina "publica" por así decirlo, esta alojada a un servidor con una dirección ip en donde solo las computadoras conectadas a red pueden acceder...

hice modificacion a mi codigo:

```
    import requests

proxies = {
   'http': 'http://99.90.124.9/',
   'https': 'https://99.90.124.9/',
}
url = 'http://99.90.124.9/'
r = requests.get (url, proxies=proxies )

print(r.text)
```

y al ejecutarlo (con una tardanza de dos minutos)
me imprime esto:
[image: lo dividi en dos partes porque el resultado era grande]
[image: esta es la segunda parte]

por lo poco que entiendo (les recuerdo que soy principiante en estos temas) no se pudo conectar con el proxy... y se excedieron los intentos.
...ustedes que me sugieren, en base a su experiencia ???

y solo por dejar a colación también intente tomar el código simple, metiendo como url, directo la dirección proxy y me arroja esto...

[image: colación]

les agradezco su tiempo, y créanme que cualquier opinión me ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/551490/edit) tu pregunta para añadir estos detalles (esta es la sección de respuestas), aunque la verdad deberías formular otra pregunta, pues este problema ya no tiene que ver con el original y si haces la edición tanto la respuesta como los comentarios estarían fuera de lugar.

Comment: gracias amigo, lo hare.